# How to write a basic custom router?

Tags: spring-integration

I am getting `unsupported return type for router` on a very naive custom router:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("fromJsonToJsonChannel")
private MessageChannel fromJsonToJsonChannel;

public AbstractMessageRouter determineTransformation(Message<?> message) {
    return new AbstractMessageRouter() {

        @Override
        protected Collection<MessageChannel> determineTargetChannels(Message<?> message) {
            return Collections.singletonList(fromJsonToJsonChannel);
        }

    };
}
```

Here is the relevant part of the xml:

```
<int:router method="determineTransformation" input-channel="inputChannel"
                default-output-channel="fromJsonToJsonChannel">
        <beans:bean class="com.poc.inject.pocinject.CustomRoute"/>
    </int:router>

<int:service-activator ref="jsonDummy" method="json2jsonConvert" input-channel="fromJsonToJsonChannel" output-channel="determineValidationChannel"/>
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean#0]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: unsupported return type for router [class com.poc.inject.pocinject.CustomRoute$1]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:184) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:175) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:227) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:497) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:465) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener$GatewayDelegate.sendAndReceiveMessage(ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.java:516) ~[spring-integration-jms-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.onMessage(ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.java:344) ~[spring-integration-jms-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:736) ~[spring-jms-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:696) ~[spring-jms-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674) ~[spring-jms-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:318) [spring-jms-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:257) [spring-jms-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1189) [spring-jms-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1179) [spring-jms-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1076) [spring-jms-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_71]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: unsupported return type for router [class com.poc.inject.pocinject.CustomRoute$1]
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.addToCollection(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:299) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.determineTargetChannels(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:186) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:171) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

The channel is auto wired correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to see more from your application and how you use that `determineTransformation()`.

The error you mention happens only in case of:

```
protected Collection<MessageChannel> determineTargetChannels(Message<?> message) {
    Collection<MessageChannel> channels = new ArrayList<MessageChannel>();
    Collection<Object> channelKeys = this.getChannelKeys(message);
    addToCollection(channels, channelKeys, message);
    return channels;
}
```

in the `AbstractMappingMessageRouter`. So, doesn't look like error is related to your custom router implementation.

Also, please, share more stack trace on the matter. And also I'm curious what makes you to go the custom `AbstractMessageRouter` implementation. Why simple `MethodInvokingRouter` is not enough for you?

**UPDATE**

You configuration is wrong:

```
<int:router method="determineTransformation" input-channel="inputChannel"
            default-output-channel="fromJsonToJsonChannel">
    <beans:bean class="com.insightguard.poc.inject.pocinject.CustomRoute"/>
</int:router>
```

This way you say to the `MethodInvokingRouter` to call your `determineTransformation` on each request message. And looking to your code you do wrong decision to create a new `AbstractMessageRouter` instance for those message.

According your request:

> The idea is to have the custom router use the message and then some DB based info (config) to determine which channel to route this to.

It is really enough to have a custom POJO method and return a desired set of `MessageChannel` s, but not a new `AbstractMessageRouter` instance for each request message. Roughly saying it must be something like this:

```
public MessageChannel determineTransformation(Message<?> message) {
     return fromJsonToJsonChannel;
}
```

Of course you can apply any custom logic there in the method, but the point is that you don't need to know anything about a `Router` abstraction there. You just follow the contract and return a `MessageChannel` or its name (or their set or array). Nothing to do with the `AbstractMessageRouter`!

Let me know if I'm still missing some your opinion!

Comment: Would be great if you share your config, more stack trace and the reason. Sorry, we don't play here spy games.

Comment: Sorry Artem. I hit enter too soon. I edited my question to include xml part and stacktrace. The idea is to have the custom router use the message and then some DB based info (config) to determine which channel to route this to.

Comment: Please, take a look into an UPDATE of my answer.